# Некорректная работа move_uploaded_file в open server

Tags: php, openserver, загрузка

Есть скрипт загрузки изображения на php.Проблема в том, что при указании пути к директории загрузки в таком виде:
`$upload_dir = 'C:\server\openserver\domains\elektra.cms/uploads/avatars/';`
все работает, а если поменять на

```
$upload_dir = 'elektra.cms/uploads/avatars/';
```

ругается, что не может найти папку.На хостинге первый вариант работать не будет.Как сделать, чтобы второй вариант работал на Open Server?
Все, решил.Добавил вначале $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].Все заработало, только вот безопасно ли это?

Comment: `__DIR__` в волшебных константах http://php.net/manual/ru/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: Прошу прощения, не указал, что папка uploads лежит в корне сайта, а скрипт в папке administrator/assets.Константа __DIR__ как я понял, выводит адрес исполняемого скрипта.В моем случае не помогает.

Comment: попробуйте `/uploads/avatars` или `../uploads/avatars`

Comment: У вас название директории не абсолютное (не начинается со слеша, или диска). А относительное название может быть относительно чего угодно - в разных местах в коде может устанавливаться разная текущая директория. Поэтому гораздо надёжнее в index объявить константу типа так: `define('APPLICATION_ROOT', __DIR__);` а дальше при любых операциях с файловой системой использовать её: `$upload_dir = APPLICATION_ROOT. '/uploads/avatars/';`

Comment: @Иван, `__DIR__` это строка, которую вы можете дописывать как хотите: `__DIR__ . '/uploads/avatars/'`.

Comment: Видимо проблема не в PHP,а в Open Server.Если поставить полный адрес, скопированный из проводника Windows, то все работает.Понятно, что на любом хостинге файловая система не такая как у винды и будет работать только второй вариант.Просто хотелось, чтобы и там и там работало